# How add a videoview programmatically

Tags: java, android

How can I add a videoview with java code to a xml file ?

Comment: you can't add it to xml file from java code but you can add it in run time  from code by add it dynamically to the layout

Comment: can you please, post here a code example of that ? Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code  i excepted that you are using `RelativeLayout`  in your xml layout

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    VideoView video = new VideoView(this);
    video.setVideoURI("yourURI");
    video.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(550, 550));
    layout.addView(video);
```

feel free to feed me in any thing not obvious for you

Comment: Thank you mohammed momn ! I'll try that code and then give return to you what I got ! Thanks again ;D

Comment: Hi again mohammed momn. The code you've gave me works fine ! Now I've another issue. I want to give "styles" to my videoview or framelayout so I can position it on the right place of my app. I used to work with  something like:


- LayoutParams rp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
- rp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
- cb1.setLayoutParams(rp);

Comment: Now how can I do the same with this code:

final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
VideoView video = new VideoView(this);
video.setVideoPath("http://tgdsrv.dyndns.org/kroosky/uploads/VID_20140128_215547.mp4");
video.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(VideoDynamic.this);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(video);
video.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
rl.addView(video); 
lm.addView(rl);

Comment: so , what's the problem you face ??

Comment: I'am using the code that you gave me and it's working fine.. but now i just don't know how can i give a rule to video to set it BELOW of something else, once i'am giving it already a layoutparams (new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200))

Answer (score 0):

I've already used something like this

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

ImageView cb1 = new ImageView(this);
cb1.setId(1);
cb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

ImageButton cb2 = new ImageButton(this);
cb2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
cb2.setBackground(null);
cb2.setId(2);

LayoutParams rp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

rp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, cb1.getId());

cb2.setLayoutParams(rp);

rl.addView(cb1);
rl.addView(cb2);

lm.addView(rl);
```

And now I want to do the same but in this code, that's the one you gave me:

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

//Create views
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

//TEXTVIEW
TextView txv = new TextView(this);
txv.setText("TEEEEEEEEEXT");
txv.setId(1);
//TEXTVIEW

//VIDEOVIEW
VideoView video = new VideoView(this);
video.setId(2);

            video.setVideoPath("http://tgdsrv.dyndns.org/kroosky/uploads/VID_20140128_215547.mp4");

        android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams fl = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        video.setLayoutParams(fl);

        //Create video controllers
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(VideoDynamic.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(video);

        //Set controllers to video
        video.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    //VIDEOVIEW     

        rl.addView(txv);
        rl.addView(video);  

        lm.addView(rl);
```